# Handle large photo upload

Tags: php, file-upload

i would like to allow users to upload photos of any size to the server quickly. after which, my program will resize the original image to thumnail, scaled and probably a max width of 1020px. because of bandwidth issues (im on shared server currently), i would need to find a way to avoid loading for too long or reaches the max upload time limit.

i understand i can do these:
1. extend the max upload time
2. set max file upload size (which im trying not to)

please advise =)

Answer (score 3):

There is no secret. The upload time depends on the users's bandwith. If he has a small bandwith the upload will take time and he maybe can reach the limit of your server.
There is no optimisation for that on your side. Moreover a shared hosting has a lot of bandwith available (several Gb) so it's probably impossible for your user to reach that limit even more in upload

Same thing with the memory limit. If you have a 8mb memory limit , trying to work on a 18MP photo will reach this limit.

Nevertheless you can seperate the two action : 
1- Upload the photo
2- Redirect with header() when upload is done
3- Resize image or put it in queue for a later processing